# Are questions that are made up of a stray lyrics here and there in the hopes of identifying a song allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For example I know UA did a song I love that I lost some where in the AppStore cloud.

It was down and melancholic so that should narrow things down a bit.

Throughout the song she keep screening out to her mom：ねえーママー

As if warning her. Random lyrics below:
この道が　｜　死んじゃうよう　｜死んじゃうから」

Reaaly sad song.

Is this sort of thing allowed?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this type of question would be suited for this site, although you can always try to ask in chat.

Firstly, I think it is quite unlikely that such a question attracts any answers. Secondly, once it is answered, the only useful information contained in the posts will be the name of a song matching certain keywords. This has little to do with Japanese as a language.

I would try to use a search engine to look for lyrics with these keywords. (Searching for `UA この道 ママ 死んじゃう` I think I found it: AJICO 『カゲロウソング』, [lyrics](http://j-lyric.net/artist/a010b99/l01275e.html), [YouTube](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=SBh6AWMKy0k).)

Comment: I. Agree just had to ask.what's fun is that I think itbmsy be a ajicosong afterall

Comment: You;re awesome! This is precisely where I needed  to ask! While that window was open.