# Is asking for song title and lyrics against the community rules?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I know some songs in Japanese from which I unfortunately don't know the title. Also, because the songs were heavily auto-tuned and the voice was synthesized, I can't hear any complete sentence that could be used in a search engine like Google and provide some hint. Is it ok to ask for advice on Japanese Stack Exchange? Does it hurt any community rules to ask for that type of help?

Answer (score 4):

Somebody asked a similar question here on meta:

[Are questions that are made up of a stray lyrics here and there in the hopes of identifying a song allowed?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1715/1628)

The purpose of the site is to build useful content and to help each other (and the many visitors) with particular aspects of the Japanese language.

Asking a question, we usually hope for serious background "research" to make the question well-posed and (together with the answers) a useful resource. 
Searching for a particular song either from text snippets or from audio clips just doesn't tick hardly any of the boxes that would make such a question a Good Question. (How many people would be searching for the same song? How many of those would identify the same text snippets? Audio clips aren't searchable... Etc.)

However, "informal" requests — such as asking to identify text on a soda can, say — are welcome in [our chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=japanese.stackexchange.com). I would suggest you try to ask there (observing the [usual rules](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/605/36660)).